# Create sequential numbers in loop

Tags: bash, awk

I need a bash script which can generate 4500 numbers in sequence and feed it as an input to an executable and repeat the process by creating next 4500 numbers and again feed to the same executable.
The script should exit once more than 90000 numbers are generated.
Right now I am using:

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 90000 ]; do
    C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe "$i"
    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

which inputs one number at a time and is a time consuming process.

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Thanking you and regards.

Comment: The cost of calling that program 90000 times will make the time taken by the shell doing arithmetic seem insignificant.

Comment: @glennjackman it'll only call it 20 times, 4500 numbers at a time.

Comment: like for example echo {1..4500} will produce a line of sequential numbers which i will feed to the executable 
in the second loop echo {4501..9000} will produce another 4500 numbers in sequence which will be fed to the executable.
this process will be continued till 90000 numbers have been generated and fed to the exe..

i hope this would help

Comment: Whagt does the code you posted have to do with 90_000 or 4500 ? `(36028797018963970 - 18014398568881984) / 10000` is a great deal more than 90_000

Comment: the exe can take a maximum 4500 sequential numbers in one line and the script can run in loop for 20 times to generate 90000 numbers.

Comment: Yes, fine, but what about that code? Why is in your question? How is it relevant?

Comment: echo {1..4500} will produce 4500 sequential numbers..i want to input this one line of 4500 numbers to the C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe 
then once again echo {4501..9000} 
the result again feed to exe in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read somewhere that *running `$(seq)` is expensive* (in the context of that discussion, not related to this question) so I decided to test running the `seq` while the `bu.exe` is running in the background:

```
for (( i=1 ; $((j=i+4499))<=90000 ; i+=4500))  # 1...4500, 4501...9000 etc.
do 
  parms=$(seq -s " " $i $j)                    # set the parameters to var
  wait $pid                                    # wait for the previous bu.exe
  bu.exe "$parms" &                            # execute bu.exe in the bg
  pid=$!                                       # store pid
done
```

Comment: i've modified this and used..it works.. thanking you and regard.. :)

Comment: Cool. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

```
$ for (( i=1; i<12; i+=3 )); do printf '####\n'; seq "$i" "$(( i+2 ))"; done
####
1
2
3
####
4
5
6
####
7
8
9
####
10
11
12
```

Replace the numbers above with your real values and depending on what it is you're really trying to do either pipe the seq output to your command:

```
$ for (( i=1; i<12; i+=3 )); do seq "$i" "$(( i+2 ))" | my_command; done
```

or call your command with the seq output as it's arguments:

```
$ for (( i=1; i<12; i+=3 )); do my_command $(seq "$i" "$(( i+2 ))"); done
```

Comment: Cutting the number of iterations by 3 but performing 3 commands now with each iteration will result with similar results... The answer should involve usage of the `&` for running as a background process which result with parallel threads...

Comment: It's not performing 3 commands with each iteration, it's calling the command once for each iteration and passing it 3 values as input. There is no hint in the question that running commands in parallel would be necessary, nor even that doing so would produce the correct output, but if the OP needs that then they can always tweak it.

Comment: im somewhat near to the solution by doing this in git shell C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe > printf {1..4500} which writes numbers in sequence in front of the exe in one line...can i automate it to write for more such printf –

Comment: Sorry idk what you're talking about. The script I posted does exactly what you asked for and executing some command with it's output redirected to the output of printf makes no sense at all so I cant imagine what makes you say you're somewhat near a solution by trying to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather advise you to execute it parallel like below. My below modification will execute 10 processes in parallel and will reduce your execution time. Please keep in mind parallel execution also depends on number of processors and memory in your system.

```
i=1
j=0
while [ "$i" -le 90000 ]; do
C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe "$i" &  
# Now you are executing parallel
j=$(($j+1))
#if 10 parallel process has been created just wait to complete them
# and re-start the parallel process again
if [ $j -ge 10 ]; then
   wait
   j=0
fi
i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Comment: this one doesnt solve the problem...the script executes with error and there are too many processes in the task manager.:(

Comment: Are running it in windows powershell?

Comment: no..im running it in git bash...
but my basic query is as in above comments.. im not well versed with programs.

Comment: what error your are getting. Please paste here in comment.

Comment: $ /c/Users/Abhi/Desktop/Untitled.sh
/c/Users/Abhi/Desktop/Untitled.sh: line 9: [: j: integer expression expected
/c/Users/Abhi/Desktop/Untitled.sh: line 9: [: j: integer expression expected
C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe: line 1: 255: command not found
/c/Users/Abhi/Desktop/Untitled.sh: line 9: [: j: integer expression expected
C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe: line 1: 255: command not found
/c/Users/Abhi/Desktop/Untitled.sh: line 9: [: j: integer expression expected
C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe: line 1: 255: command not found

Comment: I have modified my answer and fix the issue. Try and let me know.

Comment: it works now.. but it again executes like before taking one number input at a time.
i want it to be like this 

              C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.....4500

              C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe 4501 .......9000 and so on

going repeated till 90000

Comment: Better try it in Linux.

Comment: im somewhat near to the solution by doing this in git shell

C:/Python27/Scripts/bu.exe > printf {1..4500} 

which writes numbers in sequence in front of the exe in one line...can i automate it to write for more such printf